# Async await problem in nodejs sequelize connection string

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, sequelize.js

```js
function credential(secretFromVault) {
  const creddetails = new ClientSecretCredential(clientId, tenantId, cleintSecret);
  // Build the URL to reach your key vault
  const url = `https://<vaultName>.vault.azure.net/`;

  // Lastly, create our secrets client and connect to the service
  const client = new SecretClient(url, creddetails);

  const secretName = secretFromVault;
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    client.getSecret(secretName).then(latestSecret => {
      console.log(`value from secret is`, latestSecret.value);
      resolve(latestSecret.value)
    })
  })
}
const dbUserName = credential(constants.pgDbUserName)
const dbPassword = credential(constants.pgDbPassword)

const hostname = constants.pgHostname;
const port = constants.pgPort;
const dbName = constants.pgDbName;
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, dbUserName, dbPassword, {
  host: hostname,
  port: port,
  dialect: constants.dialectName,
  logging: false,
  pool: {
    max: constants.pgMaxPoolConnections,
    min: constants.pgMinPoolConnections,
    acquire: constants.pgMakeConnectionTimeOut,
    idle: constants.pgIdleTimeout
  }
});
sequelize.authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Successfully connected.');
    User.sync();
    Credentials.sync();
    App.sync();
    Entity.sync();
    EntityField.sync();
    Relationship.sync();
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Error: ' + err))
```

I am using the above code to make connection to postgres database. But I am receiving below error on execution of node index command, index.js is not attached here.
I want dbUSerName and dbUserpassword values to be passed in the sequelize connection string after fetched from the vault. but the values are promise which I am not able to resolve.

*error: uncaughtException: The "string" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received an instance of Promise*

Answer (score 1):

`credential` function returns Promise, you need to call it as a promise function.

You can read about promises here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

I think it will be better to wrap your code in a async function and use await before calling `credential`

```js
async function main() {
    const dbUserName = await credential(constants.pgDbUserName);
    const dbPassword = await credential(constants.pgDbPassword);
 
    // Your code
}

main();
```

Comment: After sequelize.authenticate, I am exporting sequelize using module.exports and using it for sequelize.define(). If I add this inside main() function, then dbUserName and dbPassword are not defined for const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, dbUserName, dbPassword. so I will have to keep it inside a function and call it from mainv fucntion. If I do so, this module.exports = { sequelize } is not working. I am not getting any idea, should I export the function ?

Comment: yes, you can export async function

Comment: If I export the function, then use this const dbConnection = require('../config/dbconfig')//the config file present above
const Credentials = dbConnection.sequelize.define('credentials', {, I am getting the below error TypeError: Cannot read property 'define' of undefined

Comment: Are you returning sequelize  from the main?

Comment: yes, I have kept it inside main, if I keep my sequelize statement outside main, then it's getting executed beofre the credentials are received from vault and I am getting, expected string but received promise

Comment: so I am keeping it inside main() and then I am getting the error

Comment: Not sure how I can resolve this

Comment: But are you returning it in main ? 
like this 

async function main() {
    ...
    return sequelize;
}

Comment: async function main() {
  const dbUserName = await secretFetch(constants.pgDbUserName);
  const dbPassword = await secretFetch(constants.pgDbPassword);
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, dbUserName, dbPassword, {
    host: hostname,
    port: port,
    dialect: constants.dialectName,
    logging: false,
    }
  });
  await sequelize.authenticate();
  User.sync();
      Credentials.sync();
      App.sync();
      Entity.sync();
      EntityField.sync();
      Relationship.sync();
      return sequelize;
})
main();

Comment: yes, I am returning sequelize

Comment: can you share module.exports  part as well ?

Comment: I think the problem is with importing and using the function.So when you are importing this main function you can get sequelize like this
const sequelize = main();

Comment: way 1-module.exports = {
  main:main
}
way 2 
module.exports = (
async function main() {
//my code 
})
main()

Comment: const dbconfig = require('the databse config file');
const Credentials = dbconfig.sequelize.define('credentials', {

This is the model file define method that I want to create table of

Comment: try this code 
const getSequelize = require('Main function path');
getSequelize().then(sequelize => {
    // your code
})

Comment: in my db configuration file?

Comment: wherever you need to access sequelize use this code

Comment: Not working, not sure if I am implementing it correctly. but it's not recognizing the define method in sequelize model. It's giving define is not a function.